# excel match function used in a formula as a refrence

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-match

I have the following formula

```
=VLOOKUP(A4,Logged!A:I,3)+VLOOKUP(A4+1,Logged!A:I,3)+VLOOKUP(A4+3,Logged!A:I,3).....
```

As it is long formula I wanted to use the `MATCH` function

```
=MATCH(A4,Logged!A:A,0)
```

which gives me a result of 12.

now all I want to do is do some thing like

```
=SUM($e$(MATCH(A4,A:A,0):$E$MATCH(A4,A:A,0)+5)
```

which I was hoping would give

```
=SUM(E12:E17)
```

but I only get an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is very confused, but from what I understood:
Build your reference in one cell, say X10:
 `="$e$" & MATCH(A4,A:A,0) & ":$E$" & MATCH(A4,A:A,0)+5`
Make sure X10 evaluates to `"$e$12:$e$17"`
After that, use `=SUM(INDIRECT(X10))`

Comment: Thats great :) wass the indirect function i needed, added togater I have =SUM(INDIRECT("Logged!$E$"&MATCH(A12,Logged!A:A,0)):(INDIRECT("Logged!$E$"&MATCH(A12,Logged!A:A,0)+5)))

Comment: +1 but why not use the `ADDRESS` function instead of this messy string concatenation business?

Comment: @Jean-François: you're perfectly right! Shame on me, I had never noticed that one :-/

Comment: oh yes thats a nice function to add in to it :) Cheers for the help guys you answered my question perfectly

Comment: Christ I must remember to read my queustion back it is very confusing... sorry about that